# What are the different ways to enter the cron job command?

Tags: php, cron

Can anyone please explain me about the different ways of entering `cron job` command in `cPanel`?

Some people write the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron/index.php
```

Some write like this:

```
php -q /home/username/public_html/cron/index.php
```

And some others write the website url in the command:

```
curl https://www.example.com/cron/index.php
```

Now I'm getting confused. I don't know which one to use over the other.

Comment: The last one would be used if the php script is designed to be executed by a webserver instead of on the command line

Comment: As for the first two, it mainly depends if you need an absolute path or whether the php executable's path is already in the default system path settings

Comment: The thing to remember when putting a command  in cron is don't assume path. Put the path to commands and files.

Comment: You can hover your mouse over the downvote button to see why downvotes may be given, and there is more detailed info in the help centre. I didn't downvote, but the question doesn't mention any of your own efforts to try and understand it, or what you thought each one might mean, or where exactly you had got confused. So people might have thought you asked without trying yourself, which isn't something the volunteers here appreciate.

Comment: @ADyson Not sure how the STO assumed that I didn't try myself. When I was trying, meantime I looked at various ways of writing cron job commands on the web by different people and it eventually made me confused. That's why I asked here to get clarification on the concept.

Comment: `Not sure how the STO assumed that I didn't try myself`...probably because there's absolutely nothing in your question about it, or giving any indication of any _attempt_ to understand or even speculate what these commands are doing? We are not mind-readers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, something like this would be the preferred method:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron/index.php
```

Always use the full path when you can, it will eliminate a lot of issues related to what user is running what shell, and what your `PATH` is, etc.

This is basically the same thing:

```
php -q /home/username/public_html/cron/index.php
```

However, note that this assumes you have `php` in your `PATH` -- which may not be true, hence why it's better to always specify the full path. The `-q` simply means don't output headers, which shouldn't exist for a cron script anyway.

Don't do this:

```
curl https://www.example.com/cron/index.php
```

This put completely unnecessary network requirements on the process, such as DNS and HTTP.

Also, and more importantly, *don't put your cron scripts in your document root*. They should never be accessible from the public web. Anybody in the world can just hit this URL whenever they want, and if that script launches a sensitive or time-crucial process, then you're gonna have a bad time.

Instead, put your cron scripts outside the document root, so they can't possibly be launched from a remote browser. Then invoke them from the CLI:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/scripts/whatever.php
```

You could also use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) inside the PHP script, to specifically launch it in the right environment:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
    // whatever
```

Then `chmod +x` the script and then you can just run it by itself:

```
/path/to/scripts/whatever.php
```

Comment: Very well explained! Thanks Alex.